# How can I manage/update my boss' contacts in Google Contacts from a delegated account?

Tags: google-contacts

How can I manage/update my boss' contacts in Google Contacts from a delegated account? Then after they are added, how do we sync them to his phone?

Comment: What kind of phone?

Comment: he is using an iPhone